# MYSQL UPDATES, DELETES, INSERTS, CREATE clauses

Tags: mysql, mysql-helper

I'm trying to create a database schema for Game achievements which should include these:

Users:
username,
avatar image file location,
achievements their received in each game

Each achievement has
achievement name
achievement level
achievement type
a game that achievement was part of. Each achievement is specific per game. You can’t have the same achievement across different games

Each game has a title and game type.

It also must have clear relationship definitions (crow’s feet for 1 to many), primary key and foreign keys should be marked.

I've started it but I'm not sure if I did it right and I'm not really sure which of the information types are supposed to be primary keys and which supposed to be foreign keys

The image shows what I have so far and where I'm stuck (stuck on the keys)
[image: database schema for Game achievements]

So this is what I've gotten now after some comments had explained a bit of this for me [image: database schema for Game achievements with foreign keys relationship]

But I'm still not really sure if I did these foreign keys correctly [image: database schema for Game achievements fk for game] [image: database schema for Game achievements fk for achievement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys must be unique value, You should give appropriate primary keys for each, as:

Users: user_id,

games: game_id,

achievements: achievement_id,

Then you can specify the foreign keys accordingly, like in achievements, user_id, and game_id will be foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Any key that you want to make foreign key then their should be a table where that key present as a primary key.
in your case Users table

1. username primary key
2. avtar_image
3. achievment_name (foreign key) reference to Achievements table (achievment_name)
   if you want game also in user table then add a new column in User table
4. game_title (foreign key) reference to Game table(game_title)